# Is there any command to copy and cd into that directory same time in terminal

Tags: command-line

I am using google cloud running on Ubuntu.

Every time when I upload a file I had to copy `cp filename.zip ../../directory/` and I had to again type the path `cd ../../directory/` to go there and unzip my file.

I need to know is there any command that I can copy and cd into that directory without typing the long directory path twice.

Comment: you can `cp filename.zip ../../directory/ && cd ../../directory/`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not one single command, but in `bash` my favorite way to do that is:

```
$ cp filename.zip ../../directory/
$ cd :ESC: .
```

In the last line I mean hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>. This combination selects the last argument from the last command, in your case that's `../../directory/`.

A different way to do that is:

```
$ cp filename.zip ../../directory/; cd $_
```

You can find similar commands over on [stackoverflow.com: How to use arguments from previous command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009412/how-to-use-arguments-from-previous-command).

Comment: You can also try `Alt+.` instead of the [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence).

Comment: 25 years of using bash and you can still learn something new about it ...

Comment: @GeraldSchneider yup, i learned that recently as well... after many years...

Answer (score 3):

You can add this function to your `.bashrc`:

```bsh
cpcd() { cp "$1" "$2" && cd "$2" ; }
```

Then, you can call `cpcd` with the file you want to copy as the 1st argument and the directory you want to copy/change into as the 2nd.

e.g. `cpcd file.txt ~/Downloads` will copy `file.txt` into `~/Downloads` , and you'll end up in `~/Downloads` as well.

You can even add `ls` to visually see that the file is indeed in the desired directory.

```bsh
cpcd() { cp "$1" "$2" && cd "$2" && ls; }
```

Or, to really guarantee it...

```bsh
cpcd() {
    cp "$1" "$2" && cd "$2"
    if [ -f ./"$1" ]
    then
        echo "Successfully copied '$1' into '$2'."
    fi
}
```

Comment: I added `.bashrc` file to my current directory with `cpcd() { cp "$1" "$2" && cd "$2" && ls; }` and use command `cpcd() public.zip ../../var/` but i am getting `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token public.zip ` any idea?

Comment: You don't need the `()` after `cpcd`. Try `cpcd public.zip ../../var/`?